# How do we obtain the integral of $\tan(x)$: is it $-\ln\left|\cos(x)\right|$ or $\ln\left|\sec(x)\right|$?

Tags: integration, trigonometric-integrals

Is the integral of $\tan(x)\,\mathrm{d}x$ equal to the negative $\ln$ of absolute value of $\cos(x)$, the same as integral of $\tan(x)\,\mathrm{d}x$ equal to the $\ln$ of absolute value of $\sec(x)$
$$
\int\tan(x)\,\mathrm{d}x = -\ln\left|\cos(x)\right| + C \equiv \int\tan(x)\,\mathrm{d}x = \ln\left|\sec(x)\right|+C
$$

Comment: Do you know the rules of logarithms?

Comment: cos(x) = 1/sec(x) and ln(1/y)=-ln(y) , so yes.

Comment: i am reviewing them now, but i noticed that they only show ln (x) and ln|x|, i guess i'm asking if the rules still apply when you go to the world of absolutes.  I can't find anything that say yes or no.  i've been taught that math is pretty strict about when and where you can apply rules.   Does it being absolute change things?

Comment: @raven065 : $$ \left| \frac 1 x \right| = \frac 1 {|x|}. $$

Comment: $$ \begin{align}
& {-\log}\left|\cos x\right| \\ {} \\
= {} & \log\frac1{|\cos x|} & & \text{(a property of logarithms)} \\ {} \\
= {} & \log\left|\frac 1 {\cos x} \right| & & \text{(a property of absolute values)} \\ {} \\
= {} & \log\left|\sec x\right| & & \text{a trigonometric identity} \end{align} $$

Answer (score 2):

So, when dealing with logarithms, you can use this following property: $\ln(\frac{1}x) = -\ln(x)$. and this is the same when working with inverse trig functions, such as cos and sec; so, $-\ln|\cos(x)$| is the same thing as $\ln|\frac{1}{\cos (x)}|$, and we know that $\frac{1}{\cos (x)} = \sec(x)$.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Answer (score 1):

As @Randall has mentioned, the following property of logarithms is useful in the present context:

\begin{align*}
\alpha\ln|x| = \ln|x|^{\alpha}
\end{align*}

At the given case, the proposed integral is given by
\begin{align*}
\int\tan(x)\mathrm{d}x = \int\frac{\sin(x)}{\cos(x)}\mathrm{d}x = -\int\frac{\mathrm{d}(\cos(x))}{\cos(x)} = -\ln|\cos(x)| + c
\end{align*}

Applying the above-mentioned property, we get that
\begin{align*}
\int\tan(x)\mathrm{d}x = \ln|\cos(x)|^{-1} + c = \ln|\sec(x)| + c
\end{align*}